# How can we send hindi font in email text body

Tags: asp.net

```
 body = "<HTML><head><META http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/></head>";
 body = "<table width='80%' cellspacing='0'>";
```

body += "दूरभाष : 0755-2**4, फैक्स : 2******";
     body += "";
    mh.SendMailmsg(EmailAddress, (body), "");

Answer (score 0):

```
mail.BodyEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
```

should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass hindi content like this :-

```
body = "<html><head></head><body>दूरभाष : 0755-2**4, फैक्स : 2******</body></html>";


 MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(senderID, recieverID, subject, body);
 msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
 smtpClient.Send(msg);
```